# ubuntu 20.04 how can i setup a dummy monitor so i can use vnc as a second screen and still be able to drag windows back and forth

Tags: 20.04, monitor

so i'd like ubuntu to believe there is a second monitor attached. the main reason is: i'd like to be able to set vnc to monitor that screen and use various devices as a second screen. for instance setting up a tablet to view that second screen with vnc and placing it beside my main screen.

also camdroid lets you broadcast a display as a webcam and record from it. by doing this from a dummy screen i can drag and drop windows into that display for a clean seamless video, without much editing.

i believe it to be similar to running a headless server anddoing a dummy monitor, but i'd like to be certain of the steps before i start, i dont want to lose my main screen for lack of experience. :)

Comment: Can you not achieve that using workspaces?

Comment: i thought of that, and i think maybe i can, but i couldn't figure out how to do vnc or camdroid from just a workspace, that isnt to say i cant, but i didn't see those options in either application, only displays.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your hardware and driver.
If you you are using intel iGPU and intel driver, you can set up with:

1. Create `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "intelgpu0"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "VirtualHeads" "1"
EndSection
```

2. Reboot and check the output of `xrandr`. You should see “VIRTUAL1 disconnected”. Also check the name of your current output. (For me it is called eDP1.) Here's mine:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
   1280x720      59.86    60.00    59.74  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82  
   960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

3. Generate modeline with gtf or cvt (Replace 1024 768 with your preferred resolution). Here is what I get:

```
$ cvt 1024 768
# 1024x768 59.92 Hz (CVT 0.79M3) hsync: 47.82 kHz; pclk: 63.50 MHz
Modeline "1024x768_60.00"   63.50  1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync
```

4. Create a new xrandr mode from previous output (Modeline keyword should be omitted):

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1024x768_60.00"   63.50  1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode VIRTUAL1 1024x768_60.00
```

5. Activate virtual display: (Replace eDP1 with your real display)

```
xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --mode 1024x768_60.00 --right-of eDP1
```

If you are not using intel driver but have a free HDMI or VGA output, you can also use it for output. Just replace VIRTUAL1 with the name of the free output in step 4 and 5.

Reference: [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extreme_Multihead#Using_a_virtual_output)

Comment: When there is an NVidia graphics card involved this will likely cause your machine to freeze during boot. Just finished recovering from that.

Comment: When I do this, at step 2, there is no virtual device.  I had to create 20-intel.conf which surprised me, but I created it both in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d AND /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d  Any way to check if it isn't loading 20-intel.conf?