# "Projecting to this pc" feature for Ubuntu

Tags: 23.04, 23.10

Is there any app that provides such "Projecting to this pc feature?"
I have Linux laptop that I would like to use sometimes as a secondary display for my windows device.

Is anything like that possible?
If not is there any project that tries to implement that? (I can maybe become contributor to that if there is one)

Comment: @guiverc That may have been a typo. The OP changed 22.10 to 23.10.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the opposite is possible, see [ubuntu 20.04 how can i setup a dummy monitor so i can use vnc as a second screen and still be able to drag windows back and forth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244067/ubuntu-20-04-how-can-i-setup-a-dummy-monitor-so-i-can-use-vnc-as-a-second-screen) so perhaps installing a vnc server on Windows can do the trick. Try and report if this works for you but this seems more a Windows issue than a Linux problem anyway also because "projecting to this pc" is a screen mirroring not a secondary display operation (not entirely true... see the answers).

Comment: Okay, thats something I could try. Well you are wrong about "Project to this pc". it acts as a second monitor, where only one of the features are the dublication ( you can also extend the screen). When you connect you look for wireless displays ( I am aware that some tvs have this feature). So I do not any reason why it could not work on linux

Comment: ok thanks, to say the truth I was not 100% sure about that. Please report if that worked for you and how...

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called scrcpy (https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) which at least should allow you to project from Android devices to your Ubuntu screen. I do not know if you can also project from Windows.